# "User is not authorized" on meanjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

I would like to ask if there is anyone getting the same response on JSON format:

> Objectdata: "User is not authorized"headers: (name) {status: 403statusText: "Forbidden"

Scenario:

1. User A post a product and add comment on the product. 
   Result: Successful.
2. User B comment on the same product:
   Result: User is not authorized.

The code I'm using to update the product comment is here:
applicationname/`

```
// Add comment to Product
$scope.comment = function(){            
    // console.log("name: ",$scope.user);
    // console.log("textarea: ",this.commentarea);

    var comment = {
        name: $scope.product.user.displayName,
        text: this.commentarea
    };

    $scope.product.comments.push(comment);

    $scope.product.$update(function() {
        console.log('success update');
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        console.log('success error', errorResponse);
    });

};
```

This is the server side.

```
'use strict';
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var init = require('./config/init')(),
    config = require('./config/config'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    chalk = require('chalk');

/**
 * Main application entry file.
 * Please note that the order of loading is important.
 */

// Bootstrap db connection
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(chalk.red('Could not connect to MongoDB!'));
        console.log(chalk.red(err));
    }
});

// Init the express application
var app = require('./config/express')(db);

// Bootstrap passport config
require('./config/passport')();

// Start the app by listening on <port>
app.listen(config.port);

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;

// Logging initialization
console.log('MEAN.JS application started on port ' + config.port);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Products schema looks like this:

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Title cannot be blank'
    },
    comments: [{
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }]
});
```

And you have restricted your products route in your `app/routes/products.server.routes.js` file like so:

```
app.route('/products/:productId')
    .get(products.read)
    .put(users.requiresLogin, products.hasAuthorization, products.update)
    .delete(users.requiresLogin, products.hasAuthorization, products.delete);
```

Then a non-authorized user cannot add a comment because they can't update the Product record.

You probably want to create a separate `CommentsSchema` and use the Mongoose `ObjectId` type to create a one-to-many relationship with the product:

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({ 
    product: ObjectId,
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Content cannot be blank'
    }, 
})
```

That will preserve the security of your product and allow non-authorized users to comment, but would require you to do slightly more complex queries to get your comments in your product view.